# Why do repcap badges exist on Meta? How did people get them?

Tags: support, badges, meta

So, I was looking at my (rather depressing) meta profile badge to-do list when I noticed something interesting:

[image]

The repcap badges are present! Upon digging a bit further into this, I noticed that people have somehow gotten the [Mortarboard badge](https://meta.askubuntu.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard). Now this is getting strange and is confusing me.

As reputation doesn't really exist or matter on meta, why do these badges even exist, really? And, how did people earn them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No reputation is earned on meta but the system still keeps track of it in the backend with vote counts.

Comment: Is there a way we can see our own backend rep, or is that a mod-only tool?

Comment: @KazWolfe There might be a data.se query for it, but I can't find one right now. Moderators cannot see this information either.